# Composer file is set up wrong? Not Auto loading my class - PHP

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOMpu.jpg]

In the above image you can see my `composer.json`. This file belongs to Freya/Loader/Assets, which you can see is expanded.

You can also see the vendor directory is created and that I have a phpunit.xml file which looks as such:

```
<phpunit
  bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
  backupGlobals="false"
  colors="true"
  convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
  convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
  convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
  >
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite>
      <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

When I run `phpunit` in the terminal while in this directory I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AssetLoader' not found in /vagrant/Freya/Loader/Assets/tests/AssetsTest.php on line 18
```

The test looks like:

```
<?php

use Freya\Loader\Assets;

class AssetsTest extends WP_UnitTestCase {

    public function testAssetsAreRegistered() {
        // $assetsToregister = array(
        //     'css' => array(
        //         'some_file' => 'http://example.com'
        //     ),
        //     'js' => array(
        //         'some_file' => 'http://example.com'
        //     )
        //     'front_jquery_version' => '2.7.1'
        // );

        $assets = new AssetLoader();
        var_dump($assets->getAssets());

    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why this file is not being required. I am using `psr-4` standards and as far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with my composer file. The class is rather long with docs, so ill paste the shell to show you the namespace and the class definition:

**AssetLoader.php**

```
<?php

namespace Freya\Loader\Assets;

class AssetLoader { ... }
```

**Did I miss something? type something wrong? Everything looks correct to me ... **

### Update one

As requested please see the bootstrap file.

```
<?php

/** ---------------------------------------------------- **/
// Require the vendors autoload file.
/** ---------------------------------------------------- **/
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

/** ---------------------------------------------------- **/
// We neeed WordPress Bootstrap files for its test.
/** ---------------------------------------------------- **/
define('WP_TEST_DIR', parse_ini_file('test-config.ini')['test-location']);

// Include the bootstrap file.
require_once WP_TEST_DIR . 'includes/bootstrap.php';

// Include the Functions file
require_once WP_TEST_DIR . 'includes/functions.php';
```

### Update 2

So Some one suggested I run `composer dump-autoload` Which I did, then I ran phpunit and I got the same issue:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
Generating autoload files

$ phpunit

Configuration read from /vagrant/Freya/Loader/Assets/phpunit.xml

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AssetLoader' not found in /vagrant/Freya/Loader/Assets/tests/AssetsTest.php on line 18
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:535
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:105
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:153
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:406
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:722
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:722
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:699
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:609
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:743
PHP  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:866
PHP  12. AssetsTest->testAssetsAreRegistered() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:866

Fatal error: Class 'AssetLoader' not found in /vagrant/Freya/Loader/Assets/tests/AssetsTest.php on line 18

Call Stack:
    0.0007     389896   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
    0.0789   13012000   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:535
    0.0789   13012648   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:105
    1.6249   38992520   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:153
    1.6292   39003688   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:406
    1.6294   39007208   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:722
    1.6305   39011272   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:722
    1.6305   39012816   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:699
    1.6306   39015248   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:609
    1.6409   39068824  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:743
    1.6409   39069592  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:866
    1.6410   39069672  12. AssetsTest->testAssetsAreRegistered() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:866
```

Comment: Are you including composers generated `./vendor/autoload.php` file in your `bootstrap.php`?

Comment: Please also post the contents of your `bootstrap.php` that you use for PHPUnit. The Composer autoloader needs to be set up in there, which might be the issue here.

Comment: @KorvinSzanto Updated to show the bootstrap file.

Comment: @helmbert Updated to show the bootstrap file

Comment: The bootstrap file looks alright. You could try to run `composer dump-autoload` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @helmbert I updated the question with details about running `composer dump-autload` Still the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Freya\Loader\Assets;
```

This doesn't mean like "import everything from this namespace" like you may be used to from other languages. In PHP, this only means: Alias `Freya\Loader\Assets` to `Assets` in this file.

This means that `new AssetsLoader()` still tries to load it from the global scope (that's why you just see `AssetsLoader` in the class not found message, instead of `Freya\Loader\Assets\AssetsLoader`).

To make this work, either use `new Assets\AssetsLoader()` (remember, we aliased `Freya\Loader\Assets` to `Assets`) or `use Freya\Loader\Assets\AssetsLoader` (this way, `AssetsLoader` is aliased to this FQCN).